# Evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( {\frac{1}{x^2}} - {\frac{1} {\sin^2 x} }\right) $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{1}{x^2}}-{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}\right)$$

Using the L'Hospital Rule I obtained the value $-1/4$, but the answer is given to be $-1/3$. I can't find the mistake. Here's what I did; please point out the mistake.

\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0}\left({\frac{1}{x^2}}-{\frac{1}{\sin^2x}}\right)&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sin x+x)(\sin x-x)}{(x\sin x)(x\sin x)} \\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x+x}{x\sin x}\right)\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\sin x-x}{x\sin x}\right) \\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\cos x+1}{\sin x+x\cos x}\right)\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\cos x-1}{\sin x+x\cos x}\right) \\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to0}\:(\cos x+1)\,\lim_{x\to0}\left(\frac{\cos x-1}{(\sin x+x\cos x)^2}\right) \\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\sin x}{(\sin x+x\cos x)(2\cos x-x\sin x)} \\[1ex]
&=-\lim_{x\to0}\left[\frac{1}{1+\cos x\left(\frac{x}{\sin x}\right)}\right]\left(\frac{1}{2\cos x-x\sin x}\right) \\[1ex]
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left[\lim_{x\to0}\,\frac{1}{1+\cos x}\right] \\[1ex]
&=-\frac{1}{4}
\end{align}

Comment: Would you show the steps you did?

Comment: Using L'Hôpital you need to apply at least twice. In this case is easier to use the asymptotic approximation $\sin x\sim_0 x$. As is said above: please, share your calculations.

Comment: Okay I'll try those. Thanks

Comment: By the way, your mistake is that you can't split the limit into two pieces unless you know the separate limits exist.  Having done that, you can't take $\sin x+x\cos x$ from one piece and put it into the other piece.

Comment: @Teepeemm Okay. Thanks that second part is what I really didn't know

Comment: You are not allowed to do the step from third to fourth line, once you have divided the expressions you need to apply l’Hopital separately for each term.

Comment: Evaluate the following comment about the title

Comment: referring to the [limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function), note that $\lim [f(x)\cdot g(x)]=\lim f(x) \cdot \lim g(x)$ if the limits on the right exist. When you separated the limit into two in line $3$, you got the first limit nonexisting ($\infty$), hence the separation is not successful. See Riemann's approach below.

Comment: [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Clim_%7Bx%20%5Cto%200%7D%20%5Cleft(%20%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bx%5E2%7D%7D%20-%20%7B%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%20%7B%5Csin%5E2%20x%7D%20%7D%5Cright)%24&p=1) finds dupes effortlessly. A downvote to every answer by a "trusted" user who didn't searh.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I can't agree with you in that case. Indeed the limit itself is clearly a duplicate but the poser is not and indeed here we are dicussing in detail some issue related to the application of l'Hopital rule. Moreover I really can't see what is the problem with such kind of duplicates those are an enrichment for the community and since the duplicates are linked togheter the fact to have different answers from different user in different time and context can be very useful also for the future. Maybe you should consider carefully all these things before judging things negatively. Bye

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/922253/11619). And [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1673231/11619) for more.

Comment: Sir. I get your point. But I wasn't wrong. And btw thanks for all the links they helped me too. I know I'll find alot of duplicates to this, I'm thankful for your insight, , now can we please let this go?

Comment: @ArchitJain Sorry I've reopened and then closed again the OP accidentally!

Comment: I reopened this  post  **only** as it is closed just due to an oversight by a user (see comment by @gimusi and the timeline).

Comment: @quid Thanks and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 11):

By l'Hopital we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1} {\sin^2 x} =\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2 x}$$

$$\stackrel{H.R.}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 2x-2x}{2x\sin^2 x+x^2\sin 2x }$$

$$\stackrel{H.R.}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\cos 2x-2}{2\sin^2 x+2x\sin 2x+2x\sin 2x +2x^2\cos 2x}$$

$$\stackrel{H.R.}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-4\sin 2x}{2\sin 2 x+8x\cos 2x+4 \sin 2x+4x\cos 2x-4x^2\sin 2x}$$

$$\stackrel{H.R.}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-8\cos 2x}{12\cos 2 x+8\cos 2x-16x \sin 2x-8x\sin 2x+4\cos 2x-8x\sin 2x-8x^2\cos2x}$$

$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-8\cos 2x}{24\cos 2 x-32x \sin 2x-8x^2\cos2x} =\frac{-8}{24-0-0}=-\frac13$$

Comment: Good steps! Had a hard job in typing. Great++

Comment: @mrs I tried to apply l'Hopital pedantically to show that it is not a convenient method to solve limits without the knowledge of standard limits. Thanks

Comment: definitively you are masochist. +1 for typing this monstrosity :)

Comment: @Masacroso I just wanted to convince myself to do never use l'Hopital blindly! :P

Comment: I hope readers are convinced (via this answer) that one should not apply L'Hospital's Rule blindly!! +1

Comment: @ParamanandSingh You know I was exactly thinking to you while typing that! Cheers

Comment: it would be easier (and L'Hospital is used thrice nicely) if it was transformed to: $\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2 x}=\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^4}$

Comment: @farruhota Yes of course. That's precisely the method suggested by mrs in the accepted answer. Bye

Answer (score 10):

Hint: Write the function as $$\frac{\sin^2(x)-x^2}{x^4}\times \frac{x^2}{\sin^2(x)}$$ Otherwise use the Talor's expantion if you know it.

Comment: And also it will help if you have memorized the "small angle approximation" $x/\sin(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$

Comment: I couldn't upload my steps right now. So I'll try these too. And yeah I know the binomial as well as the taylor approximations. But how to use L'Hospital on it?

Comment: @ArchitJain You can refer to standard limit for the second one and use l'Hopital for the first one, which is simpler.

Comment: @mrs That's the good method to simplify by standard limits!

Comment: Yeah I got it now. Thanks

Comment: Why downvote! :-(

Answer (score 10):

As an alternative by Taylor expansion as $x\to 0$

$$\sin x = x -\frac16x^3 + o(x^3)\implies \sin^2 x = \left(x -\frac16x^3 + o(x^3)\right)^2=x^2-\frac13x^4+o(x^4)$$

we have

$$\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1} {\sin^2 x} =\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2 x}=\frac{x^2-\frac13x^4+o(x^4)-x^2}{x^2\left(x^2-\frac13x^4+o(x^4)\right)}=$$$$=\frac{-\frac13x^4+o(x^4)}{x^4+o(x^4)}=\frac{-\frac13+o(1)}{1+o(1)}\to -\frac13$$

Answer (score 7):

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( {\frac{1}{x^2}} - {\frac{1} {\sin^2 x} }\right)=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2 x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\sin x-x)(\sin x+x)}{x^4}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\sin x+x)}{x}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(\sin x-x)}{x^4}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x(\sin x-x)}{x^4}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2(\sin x-x)}{x^3}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2(\cos x-1)}{3x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-2\sin x}{6x}=\frac{-1}{3}.$$

Comment: Thank You. I was breaking the limit into two separate product of limits. Maybe I made a mistake doing that

Comment: The intermediate step $$\ldots =\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\sin x-x)(\sin x+x)}{x^4}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x(\sin x-x)}{x^4}=\ldots $$ should be justified. Are you using taylor's expansion?

Comment: @gimusi and the final step also need some justification.

Comment: @Masacroso Yes even if it is just a standard limit and I can uderstand that, but the intermediat step can be considere wrong as it is presented.

Comment: just $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x+x}{x}=2$.

Comment: +1 this is exactly what I would have written as answer.

Comment: @Paramanand Singh: Thank you!!

Comment: @Riemann What I mean is that the step should be written as $$\ldots =\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\sin x-x)(\sin x+x)}{x^4}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{(\sin x+x)}{x}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x(\sin x-x)}{x^4}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x(\sin x-x)}{x^4}=\ldots$$ in order to do not give theimpression that we can always make these kind of substitution.

Comment: @ gimusi  You are right. I edit it now!

Answer (score 3):

My preferred way is to focus on one term at a time, breaking up computations of even one term into smaller parts and focusing on each part separately. By not combining all the terms into one big equation you can avoid mistakes. Also if an error is made somewhere, you can more easily spot it and correct it. So, let's start with expanding only the term involving $\sin(x)$. Using the Taylor expansion:

$$\sin(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120} +\mathcal{O}(x^7)$$

Here I've taken included more terms than I know I need, with less experience you may not know how many terms you do need. Too few terms will lead to an answer of the form $\mathcal{O}(1)$, which means that information about the answer is the in the terms you didn't include. We then expand $\dfrac{1}{\sin^2(x)}$:

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} = \frac{1}{x^2}\left[1 - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} +\mathcal{O}(x^6)\right]^{-2}$$

To expand the square brackets, we can use:

$$\frac{1}{(1+u)^2} = 1-2 u + 3 u^2 + \mathcal{O}(u^3)$$

This can be derived by differentiating the geometric series term by term. We can then substitute $u = - \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} +\mathcal{O}(x^6)$. We have:

$$u^2 = \left[- \frac{x^2}{6} + \frac{x^4}{120} +\mathcal{O}(x^6)\right]^2 = \frac{x^4}{36} +\mathcal{O}(x^6)$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{1}{1+u}= 1-2 u + 3 u^2 +\mathcal{O}(u^3)= 1 +  \frac{x^2}{3} + \frac{x^4}{15} +\mathcal{O}(x^6)$$

And we see that:

$$\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)} =  \frac{1}{x^2} +  \frac{1}{3} + \frac{x^2}{15} +\mathcal{O}(x^4)$$

The desired limit then follows immediately. Because we kept an additional term, we can compute more complex limits involving e.g. $\dfrac{1}{\sin^4(x)}$ by squaring both sides of this expansion, like:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{1}{\sin^4(x)}-\frac{1}{x^4} - \frac{2}{3 x^2}\right]= \frac{11}{45}$$

Comment: @gimusi Yes, that's a far quicker way to get to the answer (note that the sign of x/6 is positive, not negative).

Comment: ops yes of course!

Comment: I've added also a solution by that way!

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, following the idea by Count Iblis, we have that by Taylor expansion

$$\sin x = x-\frac16 x^3+o(x^3) \implies \frac1{\sin x}=\frac 1x\left(1-\frac16x^2+o(x^2)\right)^{-1}=\frac1x+\frac16x+o(x)$$

therefore

$$\left( {\frac{1}{x^2}} - {\frac{1} {\sin^2 x} }\right)
=\left( {\frac{1}{x}} + {\frac{1} {\sin x} }\right) \left( {\frac{1}{x}} - {\frac{1} {\sin x} }\right)=$$
$$=\left(\frac2x+\frac16x+o(x)\right) \left( -\frac16x+o(x)\right)
=-\frac13+o(1) \to -\frac13$$

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake probably comes from your third row, because the left limit does not exist and you may not apply L'Hospital there (and the other limit is $0$).

---

What you can do instead (notice the asymmetry):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin^2x-x^2}{x^4}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x+x}{x}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}
\\=2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\cos x-1}{3x^2}=-2\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{6x}=-\frac13.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(\sin{x}+x)(\sin{x}-x)}{x\sin{x}\cdot x\sin{x}}$$

> Here are some limits I remember that help me a lot, (easily derivable using L-Hopital)
>
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin{x}-x}{x^3}=-\frac{1}{6}$$
>
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x-\tan{x}}{x^3}=-\frac{1}{3}$$
>
> $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-1-x}{x^2}=\frac{1}{2}$$

So using this,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2x}\cdot \frac{(\sin{x}+x)}{x}\cdot \frac{(\sin{x}-x)}{x^3}$$

$$1\cdot2\cdot -\frac{1}{6}$$

$$-\frac{1}{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

As noticed in the comments, we are allowed to proceed as follows

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( {\frac{1}{x^2}} - {\frac{1} {\sin^2 x} }\right)= \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2 x} \right)=\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin x+x}{x\sin x} \right)\left( \frac{\sin x-x}{x\sin x} \right)=\ldots$$

but we are not allowed to proceed as follows

$$\ldots=\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin x+x}{x\sin x} \right)\lim_{x \to 0}\left( \frac{\sin x-x}{x\sin x} \right)=\ldots$$

when one or both limits do not exist or the product leads to an undefined expression.

Notably in that case by l'Hopital we obtain

$$\ldots=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\cos x+1}  {\sin x+x\cos x}\cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\cos x-1}  {\sin x+x\cos x}=\ldots$$

and the LHS limit, in the form $\frac 2 0$, doesn't exist while the RHS limit is equal to zero.

Therefore the initial step in that case doesn't work.

Note that in any case also the following step

$$  \ldots=\lim_{x \to 0} (\cos x+1)\,\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\cos x-1}  {(\sin x+x\cos x)^2}=\ldots$$

is not allowed since once we have divided the original limit as the product of two distinct limits we need to operate separetely on each of them when using l'Hopital or Taylor's series. Only when we have calculated the limit for each expression we know whether the initial step was allowed or not.

See also the related [Analyzing limits problem Calculus (tell me where I'm wrong).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783782/505767)

---

In that case, following for example the hint given by [mrs](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2910603/505767), a correct way to proceed by l'Hopital is as follows

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( {\frac{1}{x^2}} - {\frac{1} {\sin^2 x} }\right)
= \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^4}\cdot\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x}\right)
\stackrel{?} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^4}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x }=\ldots$$

and since, using l'Hopital for each part, we have

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^4}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin 2x-2x}{4x^3}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2\cos 2x-2}{12x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-4\sin 2x}{24x}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{-8\cos 2x}{24}=-\frac13$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x }=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2x}{\sin 2x }=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{2}{2\cos 2x }=1$$

we see that the initial step is allowed and then we can conclude that

$$\ldots= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x-x^2}{x^4}\cdot\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^2}{\sin^2 x }=-\frac13\cdot 1 =-\frac13$$

Note finally that some intermediate step can be highly simplified using the standard limit $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x }x=1$.