# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{x^4-4^x}{x-4}$, where is my mistake?

Tags: limits, functions

Once again, I am not interested in the answer. But rather, where is/are my mistake(s)? Perhaps the solution route is hopeless:

Question is: evaluate $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{x^4 -4^x}{x-4}$.

My workings are:

Let $y=x-4$. Then when $x \to 4$, we have that $y \to 0$. Thus:

$$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(y+4)^4 - 4^{y+4}}{y} = \\ = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{(y+4)^4}{y} - \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{4^{(y+4)}}{y}  $$

And this step is not allowed from the get go, as I am deducting infinities, which is indeterminate. What I should have done though:

$$4^4 \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(1+y/4)^4-1+(4^y-1)}{y} = \\ 4^4 \lim_{y \to 0} \left( \frac{(1+y/4)^4-1}{\frac{y}{4}4} - \frac{4^y-1}{y} \right) = \\
=4^4\left(\frac{1}{4} \cdot 4 - \ln 4 \right) = 256(1-\ln 4)$$

[image]

Comment: why downvote?..

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you expect people to check your work, it would be courteous to take the time to type it up and make it much easier to read.

Comment: noted. Thanks..

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal Read [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20334/498844)

Comment: I will rewrite it tomorrow. Sorry for trouble. I usually do type it.

Comment: Since answer was already given, I'll just mention that you can use l'opital's rule

Comment: It's simply the derivative of $f(x)=x^4-4^x$ at $x=4$; since $f'(x)=4x^3-4^x\log4$, we have $f'(4)=256-256\log4=256(1-\log 4)$.

Comment: @egreg That's of course the best way to solve it!

Comment: @gimusi I always tell my students that knowing derivatives is knowing *many* limits. I find a bit silly forcing people to use low level methods when better ones are available.

Comment: @egreg Yes I agree with you, once we know derivatives we can use effectively that tool to solve limits such that. Of course in my opinion that mehod is preferable to l'Hopital or Taylor in that case. For me an exception are standard limits which aredefined before derivative concept and are also a powerful tool to solve limits.

Comment: I found another mistake. We have: $\displaystyle{\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(1+x)^p-1}{x}} = p$. I am hopeless. I keep making these silly mistakes. I should retire from maths.

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal I didn't check for all the mistakes since the first one is sufficient to obtain an uncorrect result! Do not discourage for that. I can suggest to solve many limits as you can to enforce your skills on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following step is not allowed

$$\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{x^4-4^x}{x-4}=\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(y+4)^4-4^{y+4}}{y}\color{red}{=\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(y+4)^4}{y}-\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{4^{y+4}}{y}}$$

Refer also to the related

- [Analyzing limits problem Calculus (tell me where I'm wrong).](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1783782/505767)
- [Evaluate $ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( {\frac{1}{x^2}} - {\frac{1} {\sin^2 x} }\right) $](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2910595/505767)

Comment: It is not exactly "not allowed" but it creates and indeterminate and is not helpful.

Comment: @DougM It is not allowed...in that case of course. The link I gave discuss the topic in great detail.

Comment: @DougM When I claim that it is not allowed I mean that $$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(y+4)^4-4^{y+4}}{y}\color{red}{\neq}\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(y+4)^4}{y}-\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{4^{y+4}}{y}$$

Answer (score 4):

The step where you rewrite the limit as the difference of two other limits
((i) and (ii)) is not legitimate.
You can only equate a limit to a sum or difference of two limits
if both those limits converge.

Comment: If we use addition on $R\cup \{\pm \infty\}$ we can also extend the addition rules to the case $+\infty+\infty=+\infty$ and $-\infty-\infty=-\infty$ but maybe it is not the best  rigorous way to proceed.

Comment: In this case we have $+\infty - \infty.$ But I did neglect to say how in other cases one might use a sum or difference to prove a sum diverges in a particular direction.

Comment: That's just a detail, your answer is very clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can break up this limit under certain circumstances.

$\lim_\limits{x\to a} (f(x) + g(x)) = \lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) + \lim_\limits{x\to a}g(x)$

You can do it if $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x), \lim_\limits{x\to a}g(x)$ both exist and are finite.

But if $\lim_\limits{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$ and $\lim_\limits{x\to a}g(x) = -\infty,$ then you have just given yourself and indeterminate form.

You could do this:

$\lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {(y+4)^4 - 4^{y+4}}{y} = \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {y^4}{y}+ \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {4y^3}{y}+\lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {6y^2}{y} +\lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {4y}{y} + \lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac {4^4(1 - 4^y)}{y}$

Because each of those limits are defined and finite.

You could also use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: so far I've done this: $4^4\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{(1+y/4)^4-4^y}{y}$. And stuck again. I'm trying to solve it without the derivatives.

Comment: lacking for $4$ in the denominator for the "first part" and "minus one" in the numerator for the "second part". But cannot make those two things "friends".

Comment: I get $\displaystyle{4^4 \lim_{y \to 0} \left( \frac{(1+y/4)^4}{4}\cdot \frac{4}{y}-\frac{(4^y-1)+1}{y} \right)}$

Comment: I do need to rewrite them there: $\displaystyle{4^4 \lim_{y \to 0} \left( \frac{(1+y/4)^4-1}{\frac{y}{4}4} - \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{4^y-1}{y} \right)}$

Comment: The term on the left... just multiply it out.  The term on the right evaluates to $\ln 4$